# Guard scanf from reading too many characters with a define?

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf, c-preprocessor

Usually, I use a define for the size of a string, but when I use `scanf()`, I want to guard the function from reading too many characters (and reserve space for the null-terminator). I was wondering whether I could do this using my define, instead of a hardcoded magic number...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 4

int main(void) {
    char a[MAXLEN];
    scanf("%3s", a); // Can I do that with 'MAXLEN' somehow?
}
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Use MAXLEN 3; then define `char a[MAXLEN + 1]`

Comment: I have linked to the duplicate, but why don't you use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`?

Comment: I could, but I was wondering about `scanf()` @IharobAlAsimi, thanks!

Comment: @gsamaras I have posted another solution in the original question (I was posting here but it got closed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use defines to stringify:

```
#define LENSTR_(x) #x
#define LENSTR(x) LENSTR_(x)
```

then you can use:

```
#define MAXLEN 3

char a[MAXLEN + 1];
scanf("%" LENSTR(MAXLEN) "s", a);
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre because that's how one stringifies the values of macro arguments in C...

Comment: I don't get how this works but it does so I'm upvoting

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yes, but most only copy that pattern without knowing **why** this is necessary. And that does not work as expected for variable fields. What if you have a VLA?

Comment: This only works if `MAXLEN` is a decimal integer literal. It would fail for `#define MAXLEN 0x10`

Comment: This seems a nice approach to me, but I would be concerned that any attempt to protect the buffer from over-run will (I believe) leave unread input in the input buffer if the limit is reached. It's always seemed nicer to me to have an input routine that allocates space, if possible.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I forgot to type "macro". Why does it need 2 macros instead of one?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Using just one macro will expand to `"MAXLEN"`. The two level approach expands to `LENSTR_(3)` first, which will then stringify to `"3"`.

Comment: That "#x" is necessary?

Comment: @savram: The `#` is the "stringification" or "stringizing" operator in macro definitions. It turns the argument into a C string literal.

Comment: I see. I think I understand it now. Somebody said it doesn't work with 0x10, why?

Comment: @savram: Because the `scanf` format string expects the maximum length in decimal format.